# Perform arithmetic operation based on 2 numbers and 1 operator

Tags: racket

```
(define (perform-op m n opt)
    (cond                                     
    ((eqv? opt #\+)(+ m n)) 
    ((eqv? opt #\-)(- m n))
    )                
)
```

This is a snippet of the function. m and n are integers, while opt is the operator (which is + or - in this case). Is this right? I am new to rackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works, if you call it like this:

```
> (perform-op 1 2 #\+)
3
> (perform-op 1 2 #\-)
-1
```

If you expect only two operations (in this case, `#\+` and `#\-`), you can simplify that code:

```
(define (perform-op m n opt)
    (if (eqv? opt #\+)
        (+ m n) 
        (- m n)))
```

If you want to call your function like this: `(perform-op 1 2 +)` (note that `+` is symbol here, not character), you can simply write:

```
(define (perform-op m n opt)
  (opt m n))
```

and call:

```
> (perform-op 1 2 +)
3
```